# insert form data with more columns into mysql database from php page using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert, forms

I have a HTML form which has more than 25 entries.

I know how to insert normal form data into MySQL database using PHP PDO. But I just want to know if there is any alternative way in which I can store the form entries to an array and insert the data into database using the array.

Because writing an insert statement for more than 25 columns is cumbersome.

Comment: You could have a mysql table with a blob field and store the form as a JSON object, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No Asok, I have a table of more than 25 columns and in my form I have an entry for each corresponding column in the database table. Its difficult to write the insert statement with 25 column names, hence looking for any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a PDO wrapper class, I use the class below to handle most of my PDO queries:

```
class DB {
    protected
        // Return from mysql statement
        $data = array(),
        // Used for checking whether something was added to the JSON object and remove it if the table column doens't exist
        $table_cols = array(),
        // Storing the table name we are working with
        $table = '';
    protected static
        // PDO connection to the DB
        $_conn = null,
        // The DB credentials retrieved from the ini file
        $_credentials = array ();
    private
        $_id = -1,
        $_keys = array(),
        $_values = array(),
        $_last_insert_id = -1,
        $_results = array();

    //
    //  PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    //
    public function __construct () {
        if (self::$_conn === null) {
            self::setCredentials();
            try {
                self::$_conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . self::$_credentials['host'] . ";dbname=" . self::$_credentials['dbname'] , self::$_credentials['username'], self::$_credentials['password']);
            } catch (\PDOException $e) {
                DebugLog::instance('DB')->error($e, 'db_connection');
            }
        }
    }

    public function insert ($data) {
        $data = $this->checkCols($data);
        // Allows us to quickly clone data by removing the id and inserting as a new record
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            unset($data['id']);
        }
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->setDataBinding();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . self::$_credentials['dbname'] . "`.`{$this->table}` (`" . implode('`, `', $this->_keys) . "`) VALUES (:" . implode(', :', $this->_keys) . ");";
        return $this->prepareAndExecute($sql);
    }

    public function update ($data) {
        $data = $this->checkCols($data);
        if (!isset($data['id'])) {
            // Houston we have a problem, there needs to be an id to update a record
            DebugLog::instance('DB')->error("No ID set for Update: " . implode(', ', array_keys($data)), 'db_id_' . $this->table);
        } else {
            // We need to unset the id because it shouldn't be in the data binding
            // But we still hold onto it for the where clause
            $id = $data['id'];
            unset($data['id']);
            $this->data = $data;

            $this->setDataBinding();

            $sql = "UPDATE `" . self::$_credentials['dbname'] . "`.`{$this->table}` SET ";
            $query_string = "";

            foreach ($this->_keys as $i => $key) {
                $query_string .= "`{$key}` = :{$key}, ";
            }

            $query_string = trim($query_string);
            if (substr($query_string, -1) === ',') {
                $query_string = substr($query_string, 0, -1);
            }

            $sql .= $query_string . " WHERE `id` = '{$id}'";
            return $this->prepareAndExecute($sql);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function remove ($id) {
        $this->rawQuery("DELETE FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `id` = '{$id}';");
    }

    public function rawQuery ($sql) {
        try {
            $pdo = self::$_conn->query($sql);
            $pdo->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            DebugLog::instance('DB')->error($e, 'db_query_' . $this->table);
            return array();
        }
        return $pdo->fetchAll();
    }

    //
    //  GETTERS
    //
    public function getColumns () {
        return $this->table_cols;
    }

    public function getLastInsertID () {
        return $this->_last_insert_id;
    }

    public function getRecord ($id) {
        $this->_id = $id;
        $response = $this->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'");
        $this->_results = $response[0];
    }

    public function getResults () {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function close () {
        $this->setDefaults();
    }

    //
    //  PROTECTED FUNCTIONS
    //
    protected function initColumns () {
        $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . self::$_credentials['dbname'] . "' AND TABLE_NAME = '{$this->table}';";
        $response = $this->rawQuery($sql);
        if (!empty($response)) {
            return $this->parseColumns($response);
        }
        return array();
    }

    //
    //  PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    //
    private function setDataBinding () {
        $this->_keys = array_keys($this->data);
        foreach ($this->data as $k => $v) {
            $this->_values[':' . $k] = $v;
        }
    }

    private function prepareAndExecute ($sql) {
        try {
            $q = self::$_conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($q->execute($this->_values)) {
                while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
                    $this->_results[] = $r;
                }
                $this->_last_insert_id = self::$_conn->lastInsertId();
                return true;
            } else {
                DebugLog::instance('DB')->error('Failed to execute', 'db_' . $this->table);
            }
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            DebugLog::instance('DB')->error($e, 'db_' . $this->table);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function checkCols ($array) {
        foreach ($array as $col => $val) {
            if (!in_array($col, $this->table_cols)) {
                unset($array[$col]);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }

    private static function setCredentials () {
            // I actually use a config file here, instead of hard coding
            self::$_credentials = array(
                'host' => '',
                'dbname' => '',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => ''
            );
    }

    private function parseColumns ($cols) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($cols as $index => $col_array) {
            $array[] = $col_array['COLUMN_NAME'];
        }
        return $array;
    }

    private function setDefaults () {
        $this->data = array();
        $this->table_cols = array();
        $this->table = '';
        self::$_conn = null;
        $this->_keys = array();
        $this->_values = array();
        $this->_last_insert_id = -1;
        $this->_results = array();
    }
}
```

Then for each table, create a class that extends the class above. For example, lets say we have a `users` table:

```
class UsersTable extends DB {
    public function __construct () {
        // Parent constructor creates the DB connection
        parent::__construct();
        // Now let's set the desired table based on this class
        $this->table = "users";
        // Set the table columns, for mysql column validation
        $this->table_cols = $this->initColumns();
    }
}
```

Usage is than as simple as:

```
$table = new UsersTable();
$table->insert($record);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your array has the 25 values in the same order as the table you can use unnamed parameters and lazy binding See PDO [**info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute($array);
```